How to run scratch file code in IntelliJ?
I've created a scratch file in IntelliJ, but I do not know how to run it. The Kotlin editor is messed up when I try to type: it will auto-indent after function calls by 2 full indents. What is going on?

I checked and saw that there was a bug for this, but that bug was supposedly fixed so I'm not sure what is going on right now.
Tried to add a scratch file and expected to be able to have the code run.

Scratch files should have .kts extension.

It doesn't look like you've created the scratch file correctly. Like vanyochek said, Kotlin scratch files need to have .kts extensions and not .kt extensions. Does the editor look different if you create the scratch file using the steps found here? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/scratches.html#create-scratch-file
